# Создание динамических БД SqLite Android Studio

Tags: база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Здравствуйте. 
Сижу ломаю себе голову, не могу найти примеров, чтобы разъяснить для себя такой момент.
Предположим у нас не существует никакой базы данных.
Человек в приложении вводит название базы данных, строк, столбцов, содержимое. Создаётся БД. Затем человек забыл ввести ещё пару столбцов или строк и снова добавил в эту же таблицу. При каждом включении приложение уже знает какие таблицы у нас имеются.

Я примерно сейчас представляю реализацию следующим образом:
В одной БД создается простейшая таблица:
---b1 b2 b3
a1
a2
a3
Дальше вторая таблица где указаны названия
a1
a2
a3
Третья
b1
b2
b3
Возможно третья и четвертая для своих нужд.

Так вот, во всех примерах заранее создаются таблицы с нужными столбцами и дальше очень просто добавляются данные по строкам. Как в принципе и делается в одном моем приложении, где каждой моей строке соответствует массив из нескольких данных, которые соответствуют столбцам.

Так вот сам вопрос, а как можно сделать, чтобы аналогичным образом наращивались столбцы? Очень интересует данный вопрос...

В целом я понимаю, что есть Excel и при желании можно в нем все это дело провернуть, но к сожалению у меня нет такой возможности.

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите сделать ? Динамически наращивать новые столбцы ? Для чего же ? Опишите вашу задачу в одном - двух предложениях.

Comment: Я немного уже, так сказать, разогнался. Прикрутил динамическое создание таблиц в моей базе данных с прикреплёнными к ним названиями. В двух предложениях сложновато... Попробую. В общем есть таблица со строками и столбцами, пользователь добавляет название строк и столбцов и потом таблица заполняется уже числами. В данный момент меня интересует добавление новых столбцов, в которых первая строка будет отвечать за название и уже эти названия загружать в listview. Вообще мне уже кажется, что есть более простое решение. Видимо я люблю покорять Эверест.

Comment: Если ещё короче, то будет некие операции для работы с матрицами, это ещё, так сказать, начало...

Comment: Или как сделать так, чтобы считывалось все с одной строки до тех пор, пока не дойдет до конца и каждый столбец этой строки будет записан отдельно в listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, что я писал в самом начале в данный момент реализовал, пока не очень красиво, до красоты буду допиливать позже и тем самым уменьшу код.
А теперь к основному вопросу, на который отвечу сам:

**Так вот сам вопрос, а как можно сделать, чтобы аналогичным образом наращивались столбцы?**

Не торопясь я дошёл до данного куска кода. Для работы с БД у меня создан отдельный Java Class DB в нем у меня прописано:

```
public void add() {
    String SQL = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + NAME +" TEXT;";
    DB.execSQL(SQL);
}
```

Из основного класса Main:

```
DB.add();
```

И все работает.
Конечно в программе у меня немного посложней, а именно:

```
public void add(Integer a, Integer b) {
    TABLE = "A"+a;
    NAME = "B"+b;
    String SQL = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + NAME +" TEXT;";
    DB.execSQL(SQL);
}
```

Из основного класса Main:

```
DB.add(a, b);
```

В итоге я заношу заранее известную мне цифру в название таблиц, получаются A0, A1 и т.д. и в зависимости от нужной таблицы уже добавляю столбцы B0, B1 и т.д. Если конечно есть что-то проще данного способа, то с удовольствие рассмотрю.

Всем спасибо за помощь!